# How do functors work in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I'm through all the basics. But now I'm stuck, trying to get my head around functors.

I've read that "A functor transforms one category into another category". What does this mean?

I know it's a lot to ask, but could anyone give me a **plain english** explanation of functors or maybe a **simple use case**?

Comment: I found Gabriel's blog post, [The functor design pattern](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/09/the-functor-design-pattern.html), to be quite good. It's not exactly plain English but you should give it a read through and see if it helps.

Comment: Link from Anton Guryanov: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A fuzzy explanation would be that a `Functor` is some sort of container and an associated function `fmap` that allows you to alter whatever is contained, given a function that transforms the contained.

For instance, lists are this kind of container, such that `fmap (+1) [1,2,3,4]` yields `[2,3,4,5]`.

`Maybe` can also be made a functor, such that `fmap toUpper (Just 'a')` yields `Just 'A'`.

The general type of `fmap` shows quite neatly what is going on:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

And the specialized versions may make it clearer. Here's the list version:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

And the Maybe version:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

You can gain information on the standard `Functor` instances by querying GHCI with `:i Functor` and many modules define more instances of `Functor`s (and other type classes.)

Please don't take the word "container" too seriously, though. `Functor`s are a well-defined concept, but you can often reason about it with this fuzzy analogy.

Your best bet in understanding what is going on is simply reading the definition of each of the instances, which should give you an intuition on what is going on. From there it's only a small step to really formalize your understanding of the concept. What needs to be added is a clarification of what our "container" really is, and that each instance much satisfy a pair of simple laws.

Comment: From my experience i can say, that container analogy for functors made them harder to understand (especially when it comes to `IO`). So, in the beginning, one can think of them as some sort of a "computation" attached to a value, and not as a "container" containing a value.

Comment: `IO` itself is not pure Haskell. I found this explanation clearer: Consider `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. This function takes `String` and returns an `IO ()`, which can be though of as a computation, in this case output to `stdout`. The container explanation here is not as clear as computation explanation. But this is only my opinion.

Comment: @WillNess @Anton is correct. The container analogy can only be used for simplicity. However, it's not by any means well defined. Consider for example the `Const a` functor :)

Comment: There's no sense splitting hairs over an _analogy_ that was described in the answer as fuzzy. All analogies break down, and Sarah correctly pointed the OP in the direction of a fuller, more law-based understanding. Container's a good start. Producer is the next step. Computational context is nicely general but rather too abstract to start with. (In my opinion as a teacher.) The OP asked for plain English anyway, let's not get too theoretical.

Comment: In category theory, a functor is often visualised as an arrow between categories. Why is the list constructor `[]` considered a functor? Does it mean that I can visualise `[]` as functor arrow between `Hask -> Hask`? Does that further mean that as a functor `[]` maps objects such as `a` to `[a]`? But what does it mean for the `[]` functor to map morphisms? And why isn't a `[]` simply called a morphism within the category of Hask?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: All Functors in Haskell are endofunctors.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai _Does it mean that I can visualise [] as functor arrow between Hask -> Hask?_ Yes. _Does that mean that as a functor [] maps objects such as a to [a]?_ Yes.  _But what does it mean for the [] functor to map morphisms?_ In Hask, a functor comes with two bits, a map from types to types and a map from functions to functions. `[]` partners with `map` to give `[] a = [a]` for types and `map f`for functions. _Why isn't a [] simply called a morphism within the category of Hask?_ Because in Hask the morphisms are functions that act on values, not functors that act on types and functions.

Answer (score 128):

I've accidently written a

## Haskell Functors Tutorial

I'll answer your question using examples, and I'll put the types underneath in comments.

Watch out for the pattern in the types.

### `fmap` is a generalisation of `map`

Functors are for giving you the `fmap` function. `fmap` works like `map`, so let's check out `map` first:

```
map (subtract 1) [2,4,8,16] = [1,3,7,15]
--    Int->Int     [Int]         [Int]
```

So it uses the function `(subtract 1)` *inside* the list. In fact, for lists, `fmap` does exactly what `map` does. Let's multiply everything by 10 this time:

```
fmap (* 10)  [2,4,8,16] = [20,40,80,160]
--  Int->Int    [Int]         [Int]
```

I'd describe this as mapping the function that multiplies by 10 over the list.

### `fmap` also works on `Maybe`

What else can I `fmap` over? Let's use the Maybe data type, which has two types of values, `Nothing` and `Just x`. (You can use `Nothing` to represent a failure to get an answer while `Just x` represents an answer.)

```
fmap  (+7)    (Just 10)  = Just 17
fmap  (+7)     Nothing   = Nothing
--  Int->Int  Maybe Int    Maybe Int
```

OK, so again, `fmap` is using `(+7)` *inside* the Maybe. 
And we can fmap other functions too. `length` finds the length of a list, so we can fmap it over `Maybe [Double]`

```
fmap    length             Nothing                      = Nothing
fmap    length    (Just [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.573458]) = Just 5
--  [Double]->Int         Maybe [Double]                  Maybe Int
```

Actually `length :: [a] -> Int` but I'm using it here on `[Double]` so I specialised it.

Let's use `show` to turn stuff into strings. Secretly the actual type of `show` is `Show a => a -> String`, but that's a bit long, and I'm using it here on an `Int`, so it specialises to `Int -> String`.

```
fmap  show     (Just 12)  = Just "12"
fmap  show      Nothing   = Nothing
-- Int->String  Maybe Int   Maybe String
```

also, looking back to lists

```
fmap   show     [3,4,5] = ["3", "4", "5"]
-- Int->String   [Int]       [String]
```

### `fmap` works on `Either something`

Let's use it on a slightly different structure, `Either`. Values of type `Either a b` are either `Left a` values or `Right b` values. Sometimes we use Either to represent a success `Right goodvalue` or failure `Left errordetails`, and sometime just to mix together values of two types into one. Anyway, the functor for the Either data type only works on the `Right` - it leaves `Left` values alone. That makes sense particularly if you're using Right values as the successful ones (and in fact we wouldn't be *able* to make it work on both because the types aren't necessarily the same). Lets use the type `Either String Int` as an example

```
fmap (5*)      (Left "hi")     =    Left "hi"
fmap (5*)      (Right 4)       =    Right 20
-- Int->Int  Either String Int   Either String Int
```

It makes `(5*)` work inside the Either, but for Eithers, only the `Right` values get changed. But we can do it the other way round on `Either Int String`, as long as the function works on strings. Let's put `", cool!"` at the end of stuff, using `(++ ", cool!")`.

```
fmap (++ ", cool!")          (Left 4)           = Left 4
fmap (++ ", cool!") (Right "fmap edits values") = Right "fmap edits values, cool!"
--   String->String    Either Int String          Either Int String
```

### It's especially cool to use `fmap` on IO

Now one of my favourite ways of using fmap is to use it on `IO` values to edit the value some IO operation gives me. Let's make an example that lets you type something in and then prints it out straight away:

```
echo1 :: IO ()
echo1 = do
    putStrLn "Say something!"
    whattheysaid <- getLine  -- getLine :: IO String
    putStrLn whattheysaid    -- putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

We can write that in a way that feels neater to me:

```
echo2 :: IO ()
echo2 = putStrLn "Say something" 
        >> getLine >>= putStrLn
```

`>>` does one thing after another, but the reason I like this is because `>>=` takes the String that `getLine` gave us and feeds it to `putStrLn` which takes a String.
What if we wanted to just greet the user:

```
greet1 :: IO ()
greet1 = do
    putStrLn "What's your name?"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ name)
```

If we wanted to write that in the neater way I'm a bit stuck. I'd have to write

```
greet2 :: IO ()
greet2 = putStrLn "What's your name?" 
         >> getLine >>= (\name -> putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ name))
```

which is **not** nicer than the `do` version. In fact the `do` notation is there so you don't have to do this. But can `fmap` come to the rescue? Yes it can. `("Hello, "++)` is a function that I can fmap over the getLine!

```
fmap ("Hello, " ++)  getLine   = -- read a line, return "Hello, " in front of it
--   String->String  IO String    IO String
```

we can use it like this:

```
greet3 :: IO ()
greet3 = putStrLn "What's your name?" 
         >> fmap ("Hello, "++) getLine >>= putStrLn
```

We can pull this trick on anything we're given. Let's disagree with whether "True" or "False" was typed in:

```
fmap   not      readLn   = -- read a line that has a Bool on it, change it
--  Bool->Bool  IO Bool       IO Bool
```

Or let's just report the size of a file:

```
fmap  length    (readFile "test.txt") = -- read the file, return its length
--  String->Int      IO String              IO Int
--   [a]->Int        IO [Char]              IO Int     (more precisely)
```

## Conclusions: What does `fmap` do, and what does it do it to?

If you've been watching the patterns in the types and thinking about the examples you'll have noticed that fmap takes a function that works on some values, and applies that function on something that has or produces those values somehow, editing the values. (eg readLn was to read Bool, so had type `IO Bool` there's a Boolean value in it in the sense that it produces a `Bool`, eg2 `[4,5,6]` has `Int`s in it.)

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Something a -> Something b
```

this works for `Something` being List-of (written `[]`), `Maybe`, `Either String`, `Either Int`, `IO` and loads of over things. We call it a Functor if this works in a sensible way (there are some rules - later). The actual type of fmap is

```
fmap :: Functor something => (a -> b) -> something a -> something b
```

but we usually replace `something` with `f` for brevity. It's all the same to the compiler, though:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Have a look back at the types and check this always works - think about `Either String Int` carefully - what's `f` that time?

### Appendix: What are the Functor rules, and why do we have them?

`id` is the identity function:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

Here are the rules:

```
fmap id  ==  id                    -- identity identity
fmap (f . g)  ==  fmap f . fmap g  -- composition
```

Firstly the identity identity: If you map the function that does nothing, that doesn't change anything. That sounds obvious (a lot of rules do), but you can interpret that as saying that `fmap` is *only* allowed to change the values, not the structure. `fmap` isn't allowed to turn `Just 4` into `Nothing`, or `[6]` into `[1,2,3,6]`, or `Right 4` into `Left 4` because more than just the data changed - the structure or context for that data changed.

I hit this rule once when I was working on a graphical user interface project - I wanted to be able to edit the values, but I couldn't do it without changing the structure underneath. No-one would have really noticed the difference because it had the same effect, but realising it didn't obey the functor rules made me rethink my whole design, and it's much cleaner, slicker and faster now.

Secondly the composition: this means you can choose whether to fmap one function at a time, or fmap them both at the same time. If `fmap` leaves the structure/context of your values alone and just edits them with the function its given, it will work with this rule too.

There's a secret third rule that mathematicians have, but we don't call it a rule in Haskell, because it just looks like a type declaration:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> something a -> something b
```

This one stops you from applying the function to just the first value in your list, for example. This law is enforced by the compiler.

Why do we have them? To make sure `fmap` doesn't sneakily do anything behind the scenes or change anything we didn't expect. They're not enforced by the compiler (asking the compiler to prove a theorem before it compiles your code isn't fair, and would slow compilation down - the programmer should check). This means you can cheat the laws a bit, but that's a bad plan because your code can give unexpected results.

The laws of Functor are to make sure that `fmap` applies your function fairly, equally, everywhere and without any other changes. That's a good, clean, clear, reliable, reusable thing.

Comment: Editing requires a minimum of 6 changes, so commenting instead: There is a typo in `fmap (* 10)` output where 10 should be 20. Good mini-tutorial :)

Comment: Exceptionally well structured explanation, all done without using a ton of other terms that someone who doesn't understand Functors isn't going to know ('parameterized' is the chief culprit, I'd say).

Comment: Isn't `putStrLn "What's your name?" >> getLine >>= (\name -> putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ name))` the same as `putStrLn "What's your name?" >> getLine >>= (putStrLn . ("Hello, " ++))`? Which is a bit nicer.

Comment: @CameronMartin It certainly is nicer, yes. I'd use the `fmap` version in real life, though, and do `import Data.Functor` (secretly I'm nearly always using `import Control.Applicative` to get `<*>` too) so I can write like `putStrLn "What's your name?" >> ("Hello, " ++) <$> getLine >>= putStrLn`

Comment: This is the best explanation I have seen so far. Could there be a chance that you have also accidentally written a tutorial for applicative and monad? I would pay whatever you charge to see them =D

Comment: @AndrewC take a bow! Thanks a ton for your efforts in putting forward such a lucid and clear explanation!

Comment: I second that, please do one for applicative and Monad

Comment: @AndrewC awesome explanation. Loved the examples. I get it now :)

Answer (score 15):

It's important to keep separate in your head the distinction between a functor itself, and a value in a type which has a functor applied to it. A functor itself is a type constructor like `Maybe`, `IO`, or the list constructor `[]`. A value in a functor is some particular value in a type with that type constructor applied. e.g. `Just 3` is one particular value in the type `Maybe Int` (that type is the `Maybe` functor applied to the type `Int`), `putStrLn "Hello World"` is one particular value in the type `IO ()`, and `[2, 4, 8, 16, 32]` is one particular value in the type `[Int]`.

I like to think of a value in a type with a functor applied as being "the same" as a value in the base type, but with some extra "context". People often use a container analogy for a functor, which works pretty naturally for quite a few functors but then becomes more of a hindrance than a help when you're having to convince yourself that `IO` or `(->) r` is like a container.

So if an `Int` represents an integer value, then a `Maybe Int` represents an integer value that may not be present ("may not be present" is the "context"). An `[Int]` represents an integer value with a number of possible values (this is the same interpretation of the list functor as the "nondeterminism" interpretation of the list monad). An `IO Int` represents an integer value whose precise value depends on the entire universe (or alternatively, it represents an integer value that can be obtained by running an external process). A `Char -> Int` is an integer value for any `Char` value ("function taking `r` as an argument" is a functor for any type `r`; with `r` as `Char` `(->) Char` is the type constructor which is a functor, which applied to `Int` becomes `(->) Char Int` or `Char -> Int` in infix notation).

The only thing you can do with a *general* functor is `fmap`, with the type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`. `fmap` transforms a function that operates on normal values into a function that operates on values with additional context added by a functor; what exactly this does is different for each functor, but you can do it with all of them.

So with the `Maybe` functor `fmap (+1)` is the function that computes a possibly-not-present integer 1 higher than its input possibly-not-present integer. With the list functor `fmap (+1)` is the function that computes a nondeterministic integer 1 higher than its input nondeterministic integer. With the `IO` functor, `fmap (+1)` is the function that computes an integer 1 higher than its input integer-whose-value-depends-on-the-external-universe. With the `(->) Char` functor, `fmap (+1)` is the function that adds 1 to an integer which depends on a `Char` (when I feed a `Char` to the return value, I get 1 higher than what I would have got by feeding the same `Char` to the original value).

But in general, for some unknown functor `f`, `fmap (+1)` applied to some value in `f Int` is "functor version" of the function `(+1)` on ordinary `Int`s. It adds 1 to the integer in whatever kind of "context" this particular functor has.

On its own, `fmap` isn't necessarily that useful. Usually when you're writing a concrete program and working with a functor, you're working with one particular functor, and you often think of `fmap` as whatever it does *for that particular functor*. When I'm working with `[Int]`, I'm often not thinking of my `[Int]` values as nondeterministic integers, I just think of them as lists of integers, and I think of `fmap` the same way I think of `map`.

So why bother with functors? Why not just have `map` for lists, `applyToMaybe` for `Maybe`s, and `applyToIO` for `IO`s? Then everyone would know what they do and no one would have to understand weird abstract concepts like functors.

The key is the recognition that there are a *lot* of functors out there; almost all container types for a start (hence the container analogy for what functors *are*). Every one of them has an operation corresponding to `fmap`, even if we don't have functors. Whenever you write an algorithm solely in terms of the `fmap` operation (or `map`, or whatever it's called for your particular type), then if you write it in terms of functors rather than your particular type then it works for **all** functors.

It can also serve as a form of documentation. If I hand off one of my list values to a function you wrote that operates on lists, it could do any number of things. But if I hand off my list to a function you wrote that operates on values in an arbitrary functor, then I **know** that the implementation of your function can't be using list features, only functor features.

Thinking back to how you would use functorish things in traditional imperative programming might help see the benefits. There container types like arrays, lists, trees, etc, will usually have some pattern you use to iterate over them. It can be slightly different for different containers, although libraries often provide standard iteration interfaces to address this. But you still end up writing a little for-loop every time you want to iterate over them, and when what you want to do is calculate a result for each item in the container  and collect all the results you typically end up mixing in the logic for constructing the new container as you go.

`fmap` is **every** for loop of that form you will ever write, sorted once and for all by the library writers, before you even sit down to program. Plus it can also be used with things like `Maybe` and `(->) r` that probably wouldn't be seen as having anything to do with a designing a consistent container interface in imperative languages.

Answer (score 8):

In Haskell, functors capture the notion of having containers of "stuff", such that you can manipulate that "stuff" without changing the shape of the container.

Functors provide one function, `fmap`, that lets you do this, by taking a regular function and "lifting" it to a function from containers of one type of element to another:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

For example, `[]`, the list type constructor, is a functor:

```
> fmap show [1, 2, 3]
["1","2","3"]
```

and so are many other Haskell type constructors, like `Maybe` and `Map Integer`<sup>1</sup>:

```
> fmap (+1) (Just 3)
Just 4
> fmap length (Data.Map.fromList [(1, "hi"), (2, "there")])
fromList [(1,2),(2,5)]
```

Note that `fmap` is not allowed to change the "shape" of the container, so if for example you `fmap` a list, the result has the same number of elements, and if you `fmap` a `Just` it can't become a `Nothing`. In formal terms, we require that `fmap id = id`, i.e. if you `fmap` the identity function, nothing changes.

So far I've been using the term "container", but it's really a bit more general than that. For example, `IO` is also a functor, and what we mean by "shape" in that case is that `fmap` on an `IO` action shouldn't change the side effects. In fact, any monad is a functor<sup>2</sup>.

In category theory, functors allow you to convert between different categories, but in Haskell we only really have one category, often called Hask. Therefore all functors in Haskell convert from Hask to Hask, so they are what we call endofunctors (functors from a category to itself).

In their simplest form, functors are somewhat boring. There is only so much you can do with just one operation. However, once you start adding operations, you can go from regular functors to applicative functors to monads and things quickly get a lot more interesting, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

<sub><sup>1</sup> But `Set` is not, because it can only store `Ord` types. Functors must be able to contain any type.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Due to historical reasons, `Functor` is not a superclass of `Monad`, though many people think it should be.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the types.

```
Prelude> :i Functor
class Functor f where fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But what does that mean?

First, `f` is a type variable here, and it stands for a type constructor: `f a` is a type; `a` is a type variable standing for some type.

Second, given a function `g :: a -> b`, you'll get `fmap g :: f a -> f b`. I.e. `fmap g` is a function, transforming things of type `f a` to things of type `f b`. Notice, we can't get at the things of type `a` nor `b` here. The function `g :: a -> b` is somehow made to work on things of type `f a` and transform them to things of type `f b`.

Notice that `f` is the same. Only the other type changes.

What does that mean? It can mean a lot of things. `f` is usually seen as "container" of stuff. Then, `fmap g` enables `g` to act on the inside of these containers, without breaking them open. The results are still enclosed "inside", the typeclass `Functor` does not provide us with abilities to open them, or peek inside. Just some transformation inside opaque things is all we get. Any other functionality will have to come from somewhere else.

Also note it doesn't say that these "containers" carry just one "thing" of type `a`; there can be many separate "things" "inside" it, but all of same type `a`.

Lastly, any candidate for a functor must obey [the Functor laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor.html):

```
fmap id      ===  id
fmap (h . g) ===  fmap h . fmap g
```

Notice the two `(.)` operators' types are different:

```
     g  :: a -> b                         fmap g  :: f a -> f b
 h      ::      b -> c           fmap h           ::        f b -> f c
----------------------          --------------------------------------
(h . g) :: a      -> c          (fmap h . fmap g) :: f a        -> f c
```

This means that whatever relationship there exists between the `a`, `b` and `c` types by *connecting the wires* so to speak of the functions like *`g`* and *`h`*, also exists between the `f a`, `f b` and `f c` types by connecting *the wires* of the functions *`fmap g`* and *`fmap h`*.

Or, whatever connected diagram can be drawn "on the left side", in the `a, b, c, ...` world, can be drawn "on the right side", in the `f a, f b, f c, ...` world by changing the functions `g, h, ...` into the functions `fmap g, fmap h, ...`, and changing the functions `id :: a -> a` into `fmap id` which themselves are also just `id :: f a -> f a`, by the Functor laws.