# Operation on user getLine result before storing in variable (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

this is my code:

```
askPointer = do
  input <- getLine
  let newInput = map toUpper input
  [..here I will re-use new Input..]
  return ()
```

Is it possible (maybe using lamba notation), to make this code shorter in one line only?

My attempt has been unsuccessfully:

```
input <- (\a b-> do toUpper (b <- getLine ) )
```

Any suggest?

Edit: little edit to make this question looking for more generic answers (not limiting to returning functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
askPointer = getLine >>= return . map toUpper
```

If you `import Control.Applicative` you can make it even shorter:

```
askPointer = map toUpper <$> getLine
```

Considering last edit:

```
input <- getLine >>= return . map toUpper
```

or

```
input <- map toUpper <$> getLine
```

Comment: And how do I get the value of input?

Comment: can you express in a little more details?

Comment: @haskellguy: `input <- getLine >>= return . map toUpper` or `input <- map toUpper <$> getLine`

Comment: when I input only the first line I get "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression"

Answer (score 6):

Applying a function to the result of an IO operation before using it is an excellent description of what `fmap` does.

```
askPointer = do
  newInput <- fmap (map toUpper) getLine
  [..here I will re-use new Input..]
  return ()
```

So here `fmap` does exactly what you wanted - it applies `map toUpper` to the result of `getLine` before you bind that to `newInput`.

Try these out in your interpreter (ghci/hugs):

1. `fmap reverse getLine`
2. `fmap tail getLine`
3. `fmap head getLine`
4. `fmap (map toUpper) getLine`

If you `import Data.Functor` or `import Control.Applicative`, you can use the infix version of `fmap`, `<$>`:

1. `reverse <$> getLine`
2. `tail <$> getLine`
3. `head <$> getLine`
4. `map toUpper <$> getLine`

which means you could also write

```
askPointer = do
  newInput <- map toUpper <$> getLine
  [..here I will re-use new Input..]
  return ()
```

`fmap` is a very very useful function indeed to know. You could read more in this [other answer about fmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359) where I ended up writing a mini tutorial.