# Monads passing variable in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a possible way to rewrite this in a single line through the use of Monads?

```
input <- getLine
let parsed = reads input :: [(Int,String)]
```

I could not understand how I can pass input,
my attemp would be thinking about lambda notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another place for `fmap` ! Use `fmap` to change a value or values inside something else - in this case, inside `getLine`, but it's more widely useful.

```
parsed <- fmap reads getLine :: IO [(Int,String)]
```

or with `import Data.Functor` or `import Control.Applicative` you could write this as

```
parsed <- reads <$> getLine :: IO [(Int,String)]
```

The compiler might well be able to deduce you mean `Int` from elsewhere, in which case you could omit the explicit type signature.

`fmap` is a very very useful function indeed to know. You could read more in this [other answer about fmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359) where I ended up writing a mini tutorial.

Actually, if you're interested in clean ways of writing one-liners, then you should find out more about Applicative Functors.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use [`liftM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aliftM) (or [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3afmap), since [`IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#t%3aIO) also has a [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#t%3aFunctor) instance) to have it on one line,

```
parsed <- (reads :: ReadS Int) `liftM` getLine
```

But I would argue that that rarely increases readability.

Comment: [liftM docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM)

Comment: Thanks, @sinelaw, made getting the link addresses much shorter.

Comment: ...and `liftA` from `Control.Applicative` is the same thing, as is the `<$>` operator from the same module.