# Copying lines divisible by 5

Tags: haskell, if-statement, url-rewriting, eof, parse-error

It's me again:). I try to write a program which copies lines which number is divisible by 5 to another file. Here is code (sorry for Polish names):

```
import IO

przepiszConHelper :: Handle -> Handle -> Integer -> Integer -> IO ()
przepiszConHelper wejscie wyjscie liczba licznik = do
    eof <- hIsEOF wejscie
    if eof then return ()
        else
            linia <- hGetLine wejscie
            if (mod licznik liczba) == 0 then
                hPutStrLn wyjscie linia
            przepiszConHelper wejscie wyjscie liczba (licznik + 1)

przepiszCon :: String -> String -> Integer -> IO ()
przepiszCon wejscie wyjscie liczba = do
    wej <- openFile wejscie ReadMode
    wyj <- openFile wyjscie WriteMode
    przepiszConHelper wej wyj liczba 0
    hClose wej
    hClose wyj

main = przepiszCoN "wejscie.txt" "wyjscie.txt" 5
```

I think it should works... but I get one, strange error:

```
przepisz.hs:6:9:
    Parse error in pattern: if eof then return () else linia
```

Which makes no sense for me. I had been using the same expression in another programs and it worked like a harm. I tried to remove these lines and write them with different indentations (I remember that I had some issues with white-spaces before). But I still get the same error:(.

---

--edit

OK, I have first error... it's just `else do` instead of `else`. But here comes another problem:

```
przepisz.hs:11:25: parse error on input `przepiszConHelper'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if eof then return ()
    else
        linia <- hGetLine wejscie
```

Indeed, the problem is not whitespace--your issue is that you seem to expect a `do` block to extend inside subexpressions, which is not the case. The `else` clause needs to define its own `do` block:

```
if eof then return ()
    else do
        linia <- hGetLine wejscie
```

There's another error after that, however:

```
if (mod licznik liczba) == 0 then
    hPutStrLn wyjscie linia
przepiszConHelper wejscie wyjscie liczba (licznik + 1)
```

You're missing an `else` clause for this `if`. `if` is always an expression in Haskell, so it must always evaluate to *something*. If you want to express "do this `IO` action if the condition is true, otherwise do nothing" you can use `return ()`:

```
if (mod licznik liczba) == 0 
    then hPutStrLn wyjscie linia
    else return ()
```

The standard library even includes the function `when` to express this idea:

```
when (mod licznik liczba == 0) $ hPutStrLn wyjscie linia
```

If you wanted, you could rewrite the outer `if` expression the same way, and get something like this:

```
przepiszConHelper :: Handle -> Handle -> Integer -> Integer -> IO ()
przepiszConHelper wejscie wyjscie liczba licznik = do
    eof <- hIsEOF wejscie
    when (not eof) $ do 
        linia <- hGetLine wejscie
        when (mod licznik liczba == 0) $ hPutStrLn wyjscie linia
        przepiszConHelper wejscie wyjscie liczba (licznik + 1)
```

Comment: FWIW, the location of `when` in the standard library is in the `Control.Monad` module: `import Control.Monad (when)`

Comment: @luqui: Oh, bother. It's not in the Prelude? My `.ghci` file has once again led me astray.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest a different way of doing things, mainly to separate pure code from IO and use more standard functions. Also, I often try to write smaller functions than you have done, keeping each one simple and easy to maintain.

First let's keep the nth element of a list. We'll do this by zipping it with the numbers `[1..]` and then only keeping those where the number is divisible by `n`.

```
przechowac :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
przechowac n listy = [a| (a,i) <- zip listy [1..], i `mod` n == 0]
```

So for example,

```
*Main> przechowac 3 [1..10]
[3,6,9]
```

Next let's stay pure whilst using that on the lines of a String:

```
przechowacLinie :: Int -> String -> String
przechowacLinie n = unlines . przechowac n . lines
```

```
*Main> putStrLn "Hej,\nHaskell\njest\nfantastyczny"
Hej,
Haskell
jest
fantastyczny
*Main> putStrLn (przechowacLinie 2 "Hej,\nHaskell\njest\nfantastyczny")
Haskell
fantastyczny
```

Now let's wrap it in some IO. We'll make a function that applies a function to a file, saving it to an output file:

```
zastosowacFunkcje :: (String -> String) -> FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
zastosowacFunkcje f wejscie wyjscie = do
   wej <- readFile wejscie
   writeFile wyjscie (f wej)
```

(`FilePath` is a type synonym of `String` that makes type signatures clearer.)

I can use that to write your function:

```
przepiszCon :: Int -> FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
przepiszCon liczba = zastosowacFunkcje (przechowacLinie liczba)
```

In actual fact, these days I've stopped using functions like `zastosowacFunkcje` and now I'd tend to just do

```
przepiszCon :: Int -> FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
przepiszCon n wejscie wyjscie = fmap (przechowacLinie n) (readFile wejscie)
                                                     >>= writeFile wyjscie
```

because I find [`fmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359) so handy.