# How does fmap work for List

Tags: haskell, functor

[Learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass) gives description about Functor typeclass.

I can see that for list, it's implemented as follows:

```
instance Functor [] where  
fmap = map
```

But how does this work ?

In the typeclass Functor, fmap doesn't even have an implementation. All it has is just type declaration like this:

```
class Functor f where  
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Just by having the type declaration, how does Haskell figure out map operation for Lists correctly ?

Comment: You might want to read the Functors tutorial I wrote as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`map` is just a normal function with type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Unlike `fmap`, it is *not* part of the `Functor` typeclass. It works exactly how you think it does.

The idea behind typeclasses is that you use the types to figure out which implementation to use. When we say `instance Functor [] where ...`, we're telling the compiler what the implementation of `fmap` for `[]` (the list type) is.

In this case, the implementation for `fmap` is just `map`, which is a normal function.