# Implementing this monad/type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

I really cannot figure out the syntax necessary for this, and it probably comes from my lack of understanding of how types work.

I want a type `DataPoint`, which stores either a tuple `(x, dataval)` or two fields x and dataval (where x is a `Double` and dataval is a `Complex Double`.

I want a `Monad` instance where it goes something like:

```
instance Monad (DataPoint x dataval) where
    return dataval = DataPoint 0.0 dataval
    DataPoint x dataval >>= f = DataPoint x (f dataval)
```

Basically, the "value" of the monad is dataval, and x is just a part of the container.

I don't think my syntax is correct though.  If i define DataPoint as

```
data DataPoint x dataval = DataPoint { x       :: Double
                                     , dataval :: Complex Double }
```

then it should work, right?

Only I get a "kind mismatch"

```
The first argument of `Monad' should have kind `* -> *',
but `DataPoint x dataval' has kind `*'
```

Can anyone help me get the functionality/monad I am trying to acheive?

Comment: This datatype cannot be made a monad and it doesn't seem to make sense for it to be one either. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm trying to store "dataval", along with an x value associated with it.  And then using `DataPoint >>= f` to apply `f` to `dataval`, and leave `x` unchanged.

Comment: That sounds more like a plain functor, except they have to support `dataval` being any type, not just `Complex Double`. It might make more sense to just define a `fmap`-like function for your type without involving type classes at all.

Comment: how would i go about implementing/instancing that, then?

Comment: thank you for your advice, i think i have something running :)  Do you mind elaborating on how to determine if something should be a functor or a monad?  I'm not sure I understand the theoretical difference.

Comment: @JustinL. It might help to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359) where I accidently wrote a functors tutorial. Rough rule of thumb: a functor has/contains/produces a value/values that you can apply a function to, whereas a monad is usually some sort of computation that produces a value/values. (So a monad is a funtor because it produces values, but not all functors _do_ anything as such, and some cannot be made into a monad.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of syntax, it's

```
instance Monad (DataPoint x) where
    -- etc
```

Although I share hammar's concerns and think you should be trying to make it a Functor instead:

```
instance Functor (DataPoint x) where
    -- etc
```

The kind error you get

```
The first argument of `Monad' should have kind `* -> *',
but `DataPoint x dataval' has kind `*'
```

is because `Monad` and `Functor` are typeclasses that apply to higher order types (compare with `Monoid`, a typeclass that applies to simple types).

e.g. `IO Int` is *not* a monad; `IO ()` is *not* a monad; `IO` *is* a monad.

---

> I want a type `DataPoint`, which stores either a tuple `(x, dataval)` or two fields `x` and `dataval` (where `x` is a `Double` and `dataval` is a `Complex Double`.

```
data DataPoint a = DataPoint {x :: Double,
                              dataval :: a}

instance Functor DataPoint where
    fmap f dataPoint = DataPoint {x = x dataPoint,
                                  dataval = f (dataval dataPoint)}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it running :)  Do you mind elaborating on the differences between functors and monads?  I'm trying to figure it out still.

Comment: Functors and Monads are different typeclasses. Read the first few chapters of [the Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) if you've not done so yet.

Comment: Thank you @ИльяРезвов for the edit. Everyone else: this is why you should use `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` and `deriving Functor`: it reduces the amount of code you can make silly mistakes in.