# define type as Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to run the code from:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.8039&rep=rep1&type=pdf

using `ghci 7.6.3`

```
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms, TypeSynonymInstances #-}
type C m a = (a -> Action m) -> Action m
data Action m = Atom (m (Action m)) | Fork (Action m) (Action m) | Stop
```

This original form:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (C m) where
   f >>= k = \c -> f (\a -> k a c)
   return x = \c -> c x
```

gives this error:

```
Type synonym `C' should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1
In the instance declaration for `Monad (C m)'
```

Trying with the additional argument:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (C m b) where
   f >>= k = \c -> f (\a -> k a c)
   return x = \c -> c x
```

shows this error:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `Monad' should have kind `* -> *',
but `C m b' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `Monad (C m b)'
```

How to correct this definition? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273896/implementing-this-monad-type-in-haskell
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881351/why-cant-you-totally-apply-a-type-synonym-that-has-arguments-using-an-other-t

Comment: `C m` is `Cont (Action m)`, so you should just use Cont here (and if you want to see how that works, just look at the source for Cont).

Answer (score 6):

Partially applied type synonyms can't be type class instances, and the only way to avoid that in this case is to make this a data or newtype declaration.

You will have to change the definition of C to make this work to e.g.

```
newtype C m a = C ((a -> Action m) -> Action m)
```

Comment: Could you also add how the bind is expected to change? Thanks