# What does Functor's fmap tell about types?

Tags: haskell, types

What does `f a` and `f b` tell me about its type?

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I think I get the idea behind standard instances of a functor. However I'm having hard time understanding what `f a` and `f` actually represent.

I understand that `f a` and `f b` are just types and they must carry information what type constructor was used to create them and type arguments that were used.

Is `f` a type constructor of kind `* -> *`? Is `(->) r` a type constructor just like `Maybe` is?

Comment: Many people would call `(->) r` a type constructor, but that usage of "constructor" may be a bit loose. Those people mean "something whose kind has an arrow in it". But the Report reserves "type constructor" for just the new name that's put in scope by a `data` or `newtype` keyword -- e.g. `Maybe` and `StateT` but also things like `Int`, `Bool`, `()` which have no arrow in their kind. It's analogous to "value constructors" -- we would say `Nothing` is a constructor, and `(,)` is a constructor, but `(,) 5` isn't.

Comment: I think you should read this [functors tutorial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359) to help make sense of the type signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My (possibly mildly tortured) reading of [chapter 4 of the Haskell 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004) is that `Maybe` and `(->) r` are both **types**, of kind `* -> *`.  Alternatively, the Report also labels them as **type expressions**—but I can't discern a firm difference in how the Report uses the two terms, except perhaps for surface syntax details.  `(->)` and `Maybe` are type constructors; type expressions are assembled from type constructors and type variables.

For example, section 4.1.1 ("Kinds") of the 2010 report says (my boldface):

> To ensure that they are valid, type expressions are classified into different *kinds*, which take one of two possible forms:
>
> - The symbol ∗ represents the kind of all nullary type constructors.
> - If κ1 and κ2 are kinds, then κ1 → κ2 is the kind of **types** that take a **type** of kind κ1 and return a type of kind κ2.

Section 4.3.2, "Instance Declarations" (my boldface):

> An `instance` declaration that makes the **type** *T* to be an instance of class *C* is called a *C-T instance declaration* and is subject to these static restrictions:
>
> - A type may not be declared as an instance of a particular class more than once in the program.
> - The class and type must have the same kind; this can be determined using kind inference as described in Section 4.6.

So going by that language, the following `instance` declaration makes the **type** `(->) r` to be an instance of the class `Functor`:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap f g = f . g
```

The funny thing about this terminology is that we call `(->) r` a "type" even though there are no expressions in Haskell that have that type—not even `undefined`:

```
foo :: (->) r
foo = undefined

{-
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ../src/scratch.hs, interpreted )

../src/scratch.hs:1:8:
    Expecting one more argument to `(->) r'
    In the type signature for `foo': foo :: (->) r
-}
```

But I think that's not a big deal.  Basically, all declarations in Haskell must have types of kind `*`.

As a side note, from my limited understanding of dependently typed languages, many of these lack Haskell's firm distinction between terms and types, so that something like `(->) Boolean` is an expression whose value is a function that takes a type as its argument and produces a type as its result.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that f a and f b are just types and they must carry information what type constructor was used to create them and type arguments that were used.

Good explanation.

> Is `f` a type constructor of kind `* -> *`?

In effect.

> Is `(->) r` a type constructor just like Maybe is?

In effect, yes:

Yes in the sense that you can apply it to a type like `String` and get `r -> String`, just like you can apply `Maybe` to `String` to get `Maybe String`. You can use for `f` anything that gives you a type from *any* other type.

..but no...

No, in the sense that Daniel Wagner points out; To be precise, `Maybe` and `[]` are type constructors, but `(->) r` and `Either a` are sort of like partially applied type constructors. Nevertheless they make good functors, because you can freely apply functions "inside" them and change the type of "the contents".

(Stuff in inverted commas is very hand-wavy imprecise terminology.)