# First time using the Maybe type in Haskell, is my understanding wrong?

Tags: haskell

From my understanding, the Maybe type is something you can combine with another type. It lets you specify a condition for the inputs that you combined it with using the "Just... Nothing" format.

an example from my lecture slides is a function in Haskell that gives the square root of an input, but before doing so, checks to see if the input is positive.:

```
maybe_sqrt :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_sqrt maybe_x = case maybe_x of
    Just x
        | x >= 0 -> Just (sqrt x)
        | otherwise -> Nothing
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

However, I don't understand why this function uses both cases and guards. Why can't you just use guards, like this?:

```
maybe_sqrt :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_sqrt x
        | x >= 0 = Just (sqrt x)
        | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Because `x` is of type `Maybe Float`, and you can't use function `>=` with a `Maybe Float`. You have to _extract_ the `x` value out of the `Maybe`. For your function to work, it needs to have the type `maybe_sqrt :: Float -> Maybe Float`

Answer (score 8):

> the `Maybe` type is something you can combine with another type

`Maybe` is *not* a type<sup>†</sup>. It's a type constructor, i.e. you can use it *to generate a type*. For instance, `Maybe Float` is a type, but it's a different type from `Float` as such. A `Maybe Float` can not be used as a `Float` because, well, maybe it doesn't contain one!

But to calculate the square root, you need a `Float`. Well, no problem: in the `Just` case, you can just unwrap it by pattern matching! But pattern matching automatically prevents you from trying to unwrap a `Float` out of a `Nothing` value, which, well, doesn't contain a float which you could compare to anything.

Incidentally, this does not mean you to need trace every possible failure by pattern matching, all the way through your code. Luckily, `Maybe` is a monad. This means, if your function was a *Kleisli arrow*

```
maybe_sqrt :: Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_sqrt x
        | x >= 0 = Just (sqrt x)
        | otherwise = Nothing
```

(which is fine because it does accept a plain float) then you can *still* use this very easily with a `Maybe Float` as the argument:

```
GHCi> maybe_sqrt =<< Just 4
Just 2.0
GHCi> maybe_sqrt =<< Just (-1)
Nothing
GHCi> maybe_sqrt =<< Nothing
Nothing
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>As discussed in the comments, there is some disagreement on whether we should nevertheless call `Maybe` *type*, or merely a *type-level entity*. As per [research by Luis Casillas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491831/what-does-functors-fmap-tell-about-types/21493199#21493199), it's actually rather Ok to call it a type. 
Anyway: my point was that `Maybe Float` is not “an OR-combination of the `Maybe` type (giving failure) and the `Float` type (giving values)”, but a completely new type with the structure of `Maybe a` and the optionally-contained elements of `Float`.</sub>

Comment: What do people who only call things with kind `*` or `#` "types" call things like `Either Int`, `MonadReader Char`, or `'S 'Z`? Are variables that get applied to things still "type variables"?

Comment: @dfeuer: I once read the Haskell Reports very closely with this question in mind.  They don't address the question directly, but they do refer terms like `Either Int` as types.  So I say `Maybe :: * -> *` is both a type constructor and a type.

Comment: @dfeuer: [Aha, found it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491831/what-does-functors-fmap-tell-about-types/21493199#21493199)

Comment: @LuisCasillas, that looks good to me! But sometimes (as in this answer) people reject non-`*` entities as "types". I'm mildly curious what those people call such entities.

Comment: Typically, something like "type functors".

Comment: To make the distinction between `*` and `* -> *` (or generally `j -> k`) types, I would probably call the second one a "parametrized type." @comingstorm I'm not sure I've heard "type functor" before. I feel like that has the potential to cause confusion because of the "baggage" that the word "functor" has in Haskell: not all `* -> *` types are covariant or contravariant functors. I believe they are all technically functors of some sort in a categorical sense, but usually when I hear "functor" in this context I think covariant (or possibly contravariant) `Hask` functor.

Comment: "But to do a comparison like `x>=0`, you need a `Float`" No. You need the type of `x` to belong to `Ord` (which `Maybe Float` does) and to `Num` (which it doesn't (but you can define a reasonable instance)). Of course, if you do define the necessary instances, `x` will be a `Maybe Float` and `Just (sqrt x)` will be a `Maybe (Maybe Float))`.

Answer (score 3):

If your type were `maybe_sqrt :: Float -> Maybe Float` then that is how you would do it.

As it is, consider: what should your function do if your input is `Nothing`?  Probably, you would want to return `Nothing` -- but why should your compiler know that?

The whole point of an "option" type like `Maybe` is that you can't ignore it -- you are required to handle all cases.  If you want your `Nothing` cases to fall through to a `Nothing` output, Haskell provides a (somewhat) convenient facility for this:

```
maybe_sqrt x_in = do
    x <- x_in
    if x >= 0 then return sqrt x
              else Nothing
```

This is the `Maybe` instance of `Monad`, and it does what you probably want.  Any time you have a `Maybe T` expression, you can extract only the successful `Just` case with `pattern <- expression`.  The only thing to remember is that *non*-`Maybe` bindings should use `let pattern = expression` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is more an extended comment than an answer. As leftaroundabout indicated, `Maybe` is an instance of `Monad`. It's also an instance of `Alternative`. You can use this fact to implement your function, if you like:

```
maybe_sqrt :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_sqrt maybe_x = do
  x <- maybe_x
  guard (x >= 0)
  pure (sqrt x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *also* more an extended comment (if this is your first time working with `Maybe`, you may not have encountered type classes yet; come back when you do). As others already said, `x` has type `Maybe Float`. But writing `x >= 0` *doesn't* require `x` to be `Float`. What does it actually require? `>=` has type `(Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool`, which means it works for any types which are instances of `Ord` type class (and `Maybe Float` is one), and both arguments must have the same type. So `0` must be a `Maybe Float` as well! Haskell actually allows this, if `Maybe Float` belongs to the `Num` type class: which it doesn't in the standard library, but you could define an instance yourself:

```
instance Num a => Num (Maybe a) where
    fromInteger x = Just (fromInteger x)
    # this means 0 :: Maybe Float is Just 0.0

    negate (Just x) = Just (negate x)
    negate Nothing = Nothing

    Just x + Just y = Just (x + y)
    _ + _ = Nothing
    # or simpler: 
    # negate = fmap negate
    # (+) = liftA2 (+)
    # similar for all remaining two argument functions
    ...
```

Now `x >= 0` is meaningful. `sqrt x` is not; you'll need instances for `Floating` and `Fractional` as well. Of course, `Just (sqrt x)` will be `Maybe (Maybe a)`, not `Maybe a`! But just `sqrt x` will do what you want.

The problem is that it works kind of by coincidence that `Nothing >= 0` is `False`; if you checked `x <= 0`, `Nothing` would pass.

Also, it's generally a bad idea to define "orphan instances": i.e. the instance above should really only be defined in the module defining `Maybe` *or* in the module defining `Num`.

Comment: Mathematically, what you're constructing here is the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the real line. Trouble is that (much like the complex numbers) this does not really permit a topology-consistent strict weak ordering, so... I think it's quite good that we do _not_ have both `Num (Maybe n)` and `Ord (Maybe n)`.

Comment: Wait... _is_ this ordering “topologically consistent”?

Comment: "Mathematically, what you're constructing here is the one-point compactification of the real line." No, because of the definition for `Ord (Maybe a)`, `Nothing` corresponds quite specifically to _negative_ infinity. If I wanted to define the one-point compactification, I would need a `newtype` (or an actual new type) and it certainly wouldn't have `Ord`. "I think it's quite good that we do not have both Num (Maybe n) and Ord (Maybe n)." That's what I meant by the next-to-last paragraph.