# Is there a better way of doing this in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, integer-arithmetic

I have written the following to assist grand kids with their home schooling work and to keep mind working by learning how to program (I thought haskell sounded awesome).

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   putStrLn "Please enter the dividend :"
   inputx  <- getLine
   putStrLn "Please enter the divisor :"
   inputy  <- getLine
   let x = (read inputx) :: Int
   let y = (read inputy) :: Int
   let z = x `div` y
   let remain = x `mod` y
   putStrLn ( "Result: " ++ show x ++ " / " ++ show y ++ " =  " ++ show z ++  " remainder " ++ show remain )

   putStrLn ( "Proof: (" ++ show y ++ " x " ++ show z ++ ") = " ++ show (y * z) ++ " + " ++ show remain ++ " = " ++ show ((y * z) + remain))
   putStrLn ( "Is this what you had? ")
```

Is their a neater/nicer/better/more compact way of doing this?

Comment: I think it's fine - you could shorten some parts (for example *merge* `read` and `getLine` - using [`<$>`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/base/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-) and `div`/ `mod` using [`divMod`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/base/Prelude.html#v:divMod) - but I think it's fine for such a simple program

Comment: Style is mostly a preference, but I would do the following: `input <- putStrLn "prompt" >> getLine`; sequential let statements don't need a let on each line (ie replace all the lets after the first with 3 spaces), instead of having `putStrLn` in sequence, I would write `putStrLn $ "line 1" ++ "line 2" ++ "line 3"` (each string can be on its own line - as long as following lines are indented, haskell knows its part of the same statement).

Comment: @user2407038 your `putStrLn` will miss some newlines ;)

Comment: Since you are not validating the input (to see if it really can be parsed as a String) anyway, you might as well use readLn directly instead of getLine.

Comment: You might get a more thorough response on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is a site specifically for code reviews.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would benefit from a key principle: separate your pure code from your IO as much as possible. This will let your programs scale up and keep `main` breif. Lots of `let` in a big `main` isn't a very functional approach and tends to get much messier as your code grows.

Using a type signature and `readLn` which is essentially `fmap read getLine` helps cut down some cruft. (If you're not familiar with `fmap`, visit the question [How do functors work in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13134825/1598537). `fmap` is a very flexible tool indeed.)

```
getInts :: IO (Int, Int)
getInts = do
    putStrLn "Please enter the dividend :" 
    x <- readLn 
    putStrLn " Please enter the divisor :"
    y <- readLn
    return (x,y)
```

Now the processing. If I were doing more with this kind of data, or more frequently, I'd be using a record type to store the dividend, divisor, quotient and remainder, so bear that in mind for the future, but it's an overkill here.

I'm hackishly returning a list rather than a tuple, so I can use `map` to `show` them all:

```
sums :: (Int, Int) -> [Int]
sums (x,y) = [x, y, q, r, y * q, y * q + r] where
            q = x `div` y
            r = x `mod` y
```

The final piece of the jigsaw is the output. Again I prefer to generate this outside IO and then I can just `mapM_ putStrLn` on it later to print each line. I'd prefer this to take the record type, but I'm tolerating a list of strings as input instead since I'm assuming I've already `show`n them all.

```
explain :: [String] -> [String]
explain [x,y,q,r,yq,yq_r] = 
  [ concat ["Result: ", x, " / ", y, " =  ", q, " remainder ", r]
  , concat ["Proof: (", y, " x ", q, ") + ", r, " = ", yq, " + ", r, " = ", yq_r]
  , "Is this what you had? "]
```

Now we can write `main` as

```
main = do (x,y) <- getInts
          let ns = map show ( sums (x,y) )
              es = explain ns
          mapM_ putStrLn es
```

or even more succinctly, by piping together the functions `explain . map show . sums`, and applying that to the output of `getInts` using `fmap`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = fmap (explain . map show . sums) getInts
       >>= mapM_ putStrLn
```

You might notice that I added a `+r` in the proof to make `=` always mean `=`, which is the correct mathematical usage, and mirror's Haskell's meaning for =.

Comment: Thanks @WillNess, your edits are always good and _always_ welcome.