# How to print the type (Either String (IO String))?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

It's a very, very long story, and I won't bore you with it, but basically, I managed to get myself in a situation in which I need to be able to print the type `Either String (IO String)`. Any help?

Comment: To avoid this situation in the future, I'd recommend reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359) I wrote about Functor, including the sections "fmap works on Either something" and "It's especially cool to use fmap on IO".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is a one liner....

```
either print (print =<<)
```

If you want to demarcate whether it was `Left` or `Right` it's a bit more involved, see @jamsihdh's answer.

Note that this cannot be made a `Show` instance, since nothing can be purely observed about values of type `IO a`.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is not a one liner....

The `IO` monad isn't an instance of `Show`, so you can't just use `print`.  In fact, the value in the IO monad has to be obtained first.

You can view the value of `x::Either String (IO String)` by putting this in your main....

```
case x of
    Left s -> putStrLn ("Left " ++ show s)
    Right getVal -> do
             s <- getVal
             putStrLn ("Right (IO " ++ show s ++ ")")
```

and it should resolve and print the value.

---

Edit-

I've been proven wrong by @luqui, :), which is cool, because I learned something....

Of course now I need to go one step further and put out a one-liner with the appropriate Left and Right designation. :)

```
either (print . ("Left " ++)) ((print =<<) . fmap ("Right IO " ++))
```

Comment: A more succinct one liner would be: ``sequenceA >=> print``