# Converting Either a (IO b) to IO (Either a b)

Tags: haskell, types, io

Once again, through some bad, bad programming, I have managed to get myself into an awful situation with  types.

Is there any way to convert `Either a (IO b)` to `IO (Either a b)`? I know, it's not very good programming to get myself into this situation, so I'd also be open to suggestions on how to avoid situations like this.

Comment: Why don't you show us how you [keep getting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051376/how-to-print-the-type-either-string-io-string) in this situation, and maybe we can show you how to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure!

```
convert :: Either a (IO b) -> IO (Either a b)
convert = either (return . Left) (fmap Right)
```

Now, if you wanted to convert `IO (Either a b)` to `Either a (IO b)`, you'd be in trouble, but you don't, so you're ok.

Let's see how `convert` works:

- `either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`, so it takes care of pattern matching for us, figuring out whether we have an `a` or an `IO b` in your case.
- if we have an `a`, we just need to convert it to a `IO (Either a b)`. The constructor `Left :: a -> Either a b` does the first part, and `IO` is a monad, so we can use `return` to do `Either a b -> IO (Either a b)`.
- if we have an `IO b`, we need to convert it to a `IO (Either a b)`. We could do this with do notation:

  ```
  given iob = do
    b <- iob
    return . Right $ b
  ```

  using `return . Right` as `b -> IO (Either a b)`. But this is exactly the situation that `mapM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b` is for in Monads: `given iob = mapM Right iob`. Most people don't use `mapM`, though, as it's just the specialization of `fmap` to Monads, so we'll use `fmap` : `given iob = fmap Right iob`, or, pointfree : `given = fmap Right`.

Comment: ``convert`` here is actually a special case of ``sequenceA``, exported from ``Data.Traversable``.

Comment: Good point. With `liftM` used instead of `fmap` it would be a special case of `Data.Traversable.sequence` ;)

Comment: Note that the type is restricted without a good reason. This works for any monad in place of IO.

Comment: @scrambledeggs You should really turn that into an answer, even if this answer has already been accepted.